# Class 'illuminate\foundation\application' not found in /var/www/html/projectname/bootstrap/app.php

Tags: php, linux, laravel, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I want to deploy laravel project on ubuntu ec2 instance. I have installed laravel project on the server. The problem I am facing is during setup of the web page and also in laravel config settings.

I am using the following command (running on ubuntu) -

`php artisan serve --host=13.126.105.89 --port=80`

I am receiving error that

`Class 'illuminate\foundation\application' not found in /var/www/html/projectname/bootstrap/app.php`.

How can make my laravel project run?

Comment: I'm guessing you were testing on Windows. Ubuntu is case-sensitive, Windows is not, so check your app/php and make sure the case is correct for everything.

Comment: @aynber No, i am running command on ubuntu and I an receiving error on ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "vendor" folder and "composer.lock" and run:

```
composer install
```